# using the command in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Today I am facing a problem in Excel during Making a file.

Please tell me the formula. I wire the TEAM in "D4" cell than "D3", "D5" and "D6" auto fill:

[image]

For example:

[image: auto fill data require]

I have 100 teams or more than.

Comment: "Please tell me the formula" formula for what?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add more information with exactly what you need and what you have tried and you will get help.

Answer (score 0):

You need the VLOOKUP formula:

```
VLOOKUP(D4, [table range], [column number to return data for])
```

Just watch out with the merged cells. I haven't tested a VLOOKUP for you there, but when you merge cells, only the first cell in the merged range actually contains the data, but since it looks like the first row in every group is a summary, you should be OK.